# How do you inject a Logging interceptor into a Windsor Controller Factory?

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

How do you add an Exception or Logging interceptor into a Windsor Controller Factory using fluent configuration?

In my bootstrapper container I new up my installers to pass in values like assemblyName.

In my ControllerInstaller I do this, which I think is wrong and why it is not working:

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyNamed(_assemblyName)
        .BasedOn<IController>()
        .LifestyleTransient(),
    Component
        .For<IController>()
        .ImplementedBy<Controller>()
        .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<LoggingAspect>())
        .Anywhere);
```

In my loggingAspect installer I do this:

```
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IInterceptor>()
        .ImplementedBy<LoggingAspect>());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work...

```
_container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyNamed(_assemblyName)
        .BasedOn<IController>()
        .LifestyleTransient()
        .Configure(component => component.Interceptors<LoggingAspect>()));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler, I wish basic things like this were clearer in the Windsor documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice article about creating a custom Windsor Controller Factory.
[ASP.NET MVC with Windsor – programmatic controller registration](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/03/28/ASPNET-MVC-with-Windsor-programmatic-controller-registration.aspx)

And below is an example of how to register an interceptor using fluent configuration.

Putting the two together should be easy enough.  You just need to add the `.Interceptors<MyLoggingInterceptor>()` line to the registration of your windsor controller factory and/or to the registration of your controllers.

```
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IInterceptor>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyLoggingInterceptor>(),
    Component
        .For<IInterceptor>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyArgumentInterceptor>(),
    Component
        .For<IDoStuff>()
        .ImplementedBy<DoStuff>()
        .Interceptors<MyLoggingInterceptor>()
        .Interceptors<MyArgumentInterceptor>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I having problems because I new up the WindsorControllerFactory which Andre does not in his example. I also do the registration of the controller in an installer. I will add some code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IInterceptor>()
        .ImplementedBy<ExceptionHandlerInterceptor>()
        .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)
        .Named("ExceptionHandlerInterceptor"),
    Component.For<IController>()
        .ImplementedBy<Controller>()
        .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)
        .Interceptors("ExceptionHandlerInterceptor"));
```